# How to get same property at different levels with jq

Tags: json, jq

```
[{

    "name": "asd"
    "children": [
    {
        "name": "sfgdfg"
    }]
}]'
```

I can get names of all parents or children so

```
jq '.[] | (.name)'
jq '.[] | (.children[].name)'
```

How can I get both with a one liner containing a OR?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to use `..`:

```
.. | objects | select( has("name") ) | .name
```

or perhaps just:

```
.. | .name? // empty
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to combine the two queries would be to use `,`:

```
  .[] | (.name, .children[]?.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest form I think is:

```
.. | .name?
```

What does it mean?

.. is a recursive decent, producing every value.

.. | .name?

finds all the values in keys starting with **name**.

You can find more in **[here in the manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example12)**

Comment: This will work here, but in general, it will produce extraneous nulls.